# How do I keep the bottom of a <div> from touching the bottom of of the page?

Tags: html, css

This is the website, but I don't want the bottom to ever touch the end. I want a 5% space between the `div` and the end of the website when you scroll down.

This part is fine :

[image]

I don't want the bottom to touch :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put something like:

```css
body {padding-bottom: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<style type="text/css">#yourDivId {margin-bottom:5px;}</style>`

in your `<head>` section of the `html` file.